# People Picker Resolves empty single space for "AllUsers(Windows)" or "NTAUTHORITY\AllUsers"

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, people-picker, people-search

When leaving the PeoplePicker after entering single space, it automatically resolves to *"AllUsers(Windows)"* or *"NTAUTHORITY\AllUsers"*.

Why this issue happening? 
Please give your solutions/suggestions to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue happen on all people column or just a specified people column? Test in other list or other site.

Try to delete the people column and re-add it then check the results.

Make sure if there are some search rules that make this issue.

Go to CA > Search service application, do an index reset and do a full crawl. Then check the results.

Comment: This issue happening people picker column with the options People and Groups.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided in my above reply?

Comment: Yes. didn't help sorry.